# Jacobian elliptic function: unfamiliar definition

Tags: elliptic-functions

I am reading a physics book that uses a Jacobian elliptic function for a special purpose. For that i have to evaluate $\text{sn}(\zeta ; \gamma)$. However, both parameters are purely imaginary and the absolute of $\gamma$ is larger one. While i found an appropriate transformations to obtain $|\gamma|<1$, i do not know how to appropriately handle an imaginary $\gamma$.

Probably, the problem lies within the definition of the elliptic function, which looks different from what you commonly find. The book defines

\begin{equation}\zeta = \int_0^{\xi}\frac{\text{d}\xi}{\sqrt{(1-\xi^2)(1-\gamma^2\xi^2)}}\end{equation}

with

\begin{equation}\xi = \text{sn}(\zeta ; \gamma).\end{equation}

And it is not a typo from my side that integration variable and upper limit are both denoted $\xi$.

Does anybody have an idea what i have to do to compute $\text{sn}(\zeta ; \gamma)$?

Comment: Using two times $\xi$ is horrible, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions#Integral_equation which is the same after the change of variable $s=z^2$ in $\int_0^{\xi}\frac{\text{d}z}{\sqrt{(1-z^2)(1-\gamma^2z^2)}}$. From this definition of $\wp,\zeta$ we obtain the differential equation directly, and the problem is to show the double periodicity and the equivalence with the series of poles definition.

Comment: I recommend [DLMF Chapter 22: Jacobian Elliptic Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/22) for the information you need.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hints. I have to give that a try. I will get back, if I run into further trouble.

Comment: Personally, I would leave the integral's upper limit blank, and write $\int_0 f'(\xi)\,d\xi=f(\xi)-f(0)$.